# Throwing exceptions in c++ syntax

Tags: c++, exception

For throwing exceptions I know that you can declare/define the function with the implication that it throws an exception

EX.

```
void foo(void) throw(const char *) {};
```

What is the appropriate time to do this.  If we are going to declare/define it this way, do we do it with both the prototype and the definition or just the definition.  One more thing what is the syntax to do this with a constructor, if we have other stuff included.

Ex.

```
class bar
{
 bar() , a(a) would the throw go here, and would it also in the definition if written elsewhere ?
}
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that, it was deprecated in C++11 for a good reason: it does not do what people think it does.

**Update:** More information on the subject here http://www.boost.org/development/requirements.html#Exception-specification

**Another update:** As pointed out by @Steve Fallows, here is another good reference on the topic: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Comment: should you use exceptions at all, or just use them but do not specify them.  How would your use now if you don't say it does?

Comment: @rubixibuc: Specially throw(...), the only considerable exception would be throw() which in C++11 is declared as nothrow. You should use exceptions freely -to handle exceptional cases that is-, just don't use exception specifications they were a missfeature.

Comment: Here is another good reference on the topic: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Comment: @Steve Fallows: I knew I had read about it in a book somewhere! Thanks for the link, I will add it to the answer itself.